# Is it possible to disable Tomcat's local JMX server?

Tags: jmx, tomcat8

Tomcat provides various monitoring operations via JMX. The [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html) describes how to enable and disable **remote** monitoring. But is it possible to disable **local** monitoring (i.e. from within a web app deployed to Tomcat itself)?

In other words, can I count on my webapp always being able to get the local `MBeanServer` using (for example) [`JmxUtils#locateMBeanServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/support/JmxUtils.html#locateMBeanServer-java.lang.String-)?